# Define a c++ array as int[int] array(5);

Tags: c++, templates, vector, operator-overloading, freefem++

I was experimenting with `FreeFem++`, which is basically a `c++` compiler with some added libraries.

As you can see here: https://doc.freefem.org/references/types.html a 5-element array can be defined and printed as:

```
int n = 5;
real[int] Ai(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    Ai[i] = i;
cout << Ai << endl;
```

(note that real is a custom type which is in fact a double).

As a (novice) `c++` developer, I would have defined the class `real` using templates, and with the proper constructor I would have been able to do the same with some call like `real<int>`.

**Question**

is it possible to write a `c++` library to make the above `FreeFem++` code work (specifically, I want squared `[]` brackets, not `<>`)?

**My attempt**

Being `FreeFem++` open source, I tried to have a look a t the code.

https://github.com/FreeFem/FreeFem-sources/blob/master/src/fflib/array_real.cpp

I can not really decipher it, however my guess is that it is not possible, and in fact is the `FreeFem++` compiler that swaps the `[int]` with some `<int>`.

**Bonus**

Sometimes I also see parts of code like

```
cout << v[] << endl;
```

where it prints a vector, however to access elements of the vector I have to do `v[][5]`. What kind of sorcery is that? Overloading `operator[](void)` would never work, right?

Comment: Not only "some added libraries", but a whole new language I would argue. The compiler might generate C++ code, and use a syntax based on or derived from C++, but things like `real[int] Ai(n);` definitely isn't C++. And no it's not possible to get it to work in C++ using the FreeFEM syntax, it's not possible to add brand new constructs and syntax in C++.

Comment: "*specifically, I want squared `[]` brackets, not `<>`*" Why is that so important? In C++, `<>` are used for templates, and `[]` are used for arrays. It's simple, and everyone knows what it's doing.

Comment: "*FreeFem++, which is basically a c++ compiler with some added libraries*" No, it's not. It's its own language.

Comment: FreeFem++ is written in C++.  But many languages are written in C++.  That doesn't make the language C++.

Comment: Ok, I went to the github link.  It's a different language altogether.  This is no different than Python, C# or a JVM written in C++, and claiming they are "C++ with additional libraries".

Comment: Java was also written in C++, does that make Java C++??

Comment: Guys, I might have made the wrong assumptions on `FreeFem++`, ok? Maybe it is not `c++` with added libraries (even if, come on, how many languages use `cout`, `endl` and have analogous similarities?).

Comment: But still, the question is not that. The question is whether is it possible to write the same thing in `c++`. I am aware that templates require angular brackets, but are you all so confident that it is not possible with a wise use of macros and `#DEEFINE`?

Comment: So please, try to stick to the point. As a matter of respect, I ask you to stop fantasizing on how I thought that `FreeFem++` was `c++` in disguise. @PaulMcKenzie first said that a language written in c++ is not necessarily c++, I have never thought anything different from that. I find offensive that you think I am that simple minded. And I find offensive that also @yunfei-chen felt the ned to restate that. Do you think I am so stupid that I would not undestrand that even after Paul's comment?